# Send and recieve JSON to<>from another server and render answer in HTML ( PHP script )

Tags: php, html, json, curl

I want to create PHP script that sends data (text) from HTML form (in JSON format) to another server and recieves data in reformatted JSON (this server sends only JSON). I made already a part of such a script but I have a problem rendering the response as HTML.

**My code:** (index.php)

```html
<fieldset>
 <legend>Form</legend>
 <form action="index.php" method="post"><textarea cols="30" name="inputtext" rows="10"> </textarea><br /> <input name="wczytaj" type="submit" value="submit" /></form>
</fieldset>

<?php

$data = array(
  "rescaleWeights"=>"true",
  "opinions"=> array($_POST['inputtext'])
  
);

$url_send ="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/sen-analysis";
$str_data = json_encode($data); 

function sendPostData($url, $str_data){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$str_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);  
  return $result;
}

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);

?>
```

The response for blank form is:

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 10:42:26 GMT {"parsedOpinions":[],"sentimentTypeSummaries":[]}
```

**The response for text** (*Operacja Iskra – ofensywna operacja wojsk radzieckich podczas II wojny światowej, której celem było przerwanie trwającej od września 1941 r. niemieckiej blokady Leningradu. Prace nad przygotowaniem operacji rozpoczęły się wkrótce po zakończeniu nieudanej ofensywy siniawińskiej. Porażka Niemców w bitwie stalingradzkiej w końcu 1942 r., znacząco osłabiła zdolności bojowe Wehrmachtu na froncie wschodnim. W styczniu 1943 r. wojska Związku Radzieckiego planowały lub przeprowadzały działania ofensywne wzdłuż całej linii frontu niemiecko-radzieckiego, w szczególności na terenach południowej Rosji. Operacja Iskra stała się częścią szerszej, zimowej kontrofensywy sił radzieckich przeprowadzonej na przełomie lat 1942–1943[5]*) **is :**

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 10:43:53 GMT {"parsedOpinions":[{"type":"NEGATIVE","weight":-1.0,"panelClass":"negative-sentiment10","heading":"Operacja Iskra – ofensywna operacja wojsk radzieckich podczas II wojny światowej, której celem było przerwanie trwającej od września 1941 r. niemieckiej blokady Leningradu. ","content":"Operacja Iskra – ofensywna operacja wojsk radzieckich podczas II wojny światowej, której celem było przerwanie trwającej od września 1941 r. niemieckiej blokady Leningradu. Prace nad przygotowaniem operacji rozpoczęły się wkrótce po zakończeniu nieudanej ofensywy siniawińskiej. Porażka Niemców w bitwie stalingradzkiej w końcu 1942 r., znacząco osłabiła zdolności bojowe Wehrmachtu na froncie wschodnim. W styczniu 1943 r. wojska Związku Radzieckiego planowały lub przeprowadzały działania ofensywne wzdłuż całej linii frontu niemiecko-radzieckiego, w szczególności na terenach południowej Rosji. Operacja Iskra stała się częścią szerszej, zimowej kontrofensywy sił radzieckich przeprowadzonej na przełomie lat 1942–1943[5] ","collocations":[{"cssClass":"positive","weight":58.0,"content":"częścią szerszej","type":"POSITIVE"},{"cssClass":"negative","weight":55.0,"content":"osłabiła zdolności bojowe","type":"NEGATIVE"},{"cssClass":"negative","weight":14.0,"content":"przerwanie trwającej","type":"NEGATIVE"}]}],"sentimentTypeSummaries":[{"name":"POSITIVE","collocations":[{"type":"POSITIVE","content":"częścią szerszej","weight":58.0,"count":1}]},{"name":"NEGATIVE","collocations":[{"type":"NEGATIVE","content":"osłabiła zdolności bojowe","weight":55.0,"count":1},{"type":"NEGATIVE","content":"przerwanie trwającej","weight":14.0,"count":1}]}]}
```

**Is there any way to view this answer in HTML? without additional information about the status before JSON?**

Answer (score 1):

you can use php objects and then convert into json:

`$obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->someName= $_POST['inputtext'];
    $str_data = json_encode($obj);
    $sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);`

Comment: Thanks but I already have it in JSON (sent and recieved data). I need to parse the answer viewed below the form as HTML. Here is the image: https://s23.postimg.org/vavt4nyrv/php.png